# How do I add things like a background or an input box to a new window that's opened?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I want to know how to customize the new window that is opened, by pressing a button in the main window. Here is the code I am using:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

root = Tk()

def create_window():
    tk.Toplevel(root)

button1 = Button(root, text = "Add a task", command = create_window)
button1.place(x=1, y=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Here is the code im using, I want to add an input box where I can write stuff into and the things I write go on the first window. Is that a little too complicated for a beginner like me?

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

root = Tk()


def create_window():
    tk.Toplevel(root)

button1 = Button(root, text = "Add a task", command = create_window) #Makes a button with a commmand to open another window
button1.place(x=1, y=1) #Button position

root.state("zoomed") #Maximizes the window

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. You do it exactly the same was as you would do it for the root window. Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: @BryanOakley I added the code im using, and wrote what I want to do with it. Can you help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the configuration of a `tk.TopLevel` upon clicking a button. In the following example, the background color of each opened `TopLevel` window is randomly set/reset upon pressing the `Customize` button:

[image]

```
import random
import tkinter as tk
from _tkinter import TclError


COLORS = ['blue', 'yellow', 'red', 'green']


def create_window():
    toplevels.append(tk.Toplevel(root))

def customize_top():
    for toplevel in toplevels:
        try:
            toplevel.configure(bg=random.choice(COLORS))
        except TclError:
            pass


root = tk.Tk()

toplevels = []

button1 = tk.Button(root, text = "Add a task", command=create_window)
button1.pack()
button2 = tk.Button(root, text = "Customize", command=customize_top)
button2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```